# What are the intermediate fields of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}})$ (Galois group)

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

The elements of Galois group are

\begin{align*}
\sigma _1:\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2,e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}]&\longrightarrow \mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2,e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}],\\
\sqrt[3]{2}&\longmapsto \sqrt[3]{2},\\
e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}&\longmapsto e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}},
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\sigma _2:\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2,e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}]&\longrightarrow \mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2,e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}],\\
\sqrt[3]{2}&\longmapsto \sqrt[3]{2}e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}},\\
e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}&\longmapsto e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}},
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\sigma _3:\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2,e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}]&\longrightarrow \mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2,e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}],\\
\sqrt[3]{2}&\longmapsto \sqrt[3]{2}e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}},\\
e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}&\longmapsto e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}},
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\sigma _4:\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2,e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}]&\longrightarrow \mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2,e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}],\\
\sqrt[3]{2}&\longmapsto \sqrt[3]{2},\\
e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}&\longmapsto e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}},
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\sigma _5:\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2,e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}]&\longrightarrow \mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2,e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}],\\
\sqrt[3]{2}&\longmapsto \sqrt[3]{2}e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}},\\
e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}&\longmapsto e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}},
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\sigma _6:\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2,e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}]&\longrightarrow \mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2,e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}],\\
\sqrt[3]{2}&\longmapsto \sqrt[3]{2}e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}},\\
e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}&\longmapsto e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}}.
\end{align*}

We remark that

\begin{align*}
\sigma _2^3=1\\
\sigma _3^3=1\\
\sigma _4^2=1\\
\sigma _5^2=1\\
\sigma_6^2=1
\end{align*}
But $$\sigma _2\sigma _4(\sqrt[3]2)=\sigma _2(\sqrt[3]2)=\sqrt[3]2e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}$$
and
$$\sigma _4\sigma _2(\sqrt[3]2)=\sigma _4(\sqrt[3]2e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}})=\sqrt[3]2e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}},$$
therefore $\{\sigma _i\}_{i=1}^6$ is not a commutatif group and thus
$$\text{Gal}(E/\mathbb Q)=\{\sigma _i\}_{i=1}^6\cong \mathfrak S_3.$$

My problem is that it should have a $\sigma _i$ such that $\sigma _i^6=1$ and $\sigma _i^n\neq 1$ for $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ because one of my intermediate field must be $\mathbb Q$. And if not, is there a mistake in my applications $\sigma _i$?

Answer (score 1):

The subfields are the fields fixed by a *subgroup* of the Galois group. Not every subgroup is generated by a single element, whence it is no problem that there is no element of order $6$.

Answer (score 1):

As you have found $Aut_{\mathbb{Q}}L \simeq S_3$ then the intermediate fields of $Gal (X^3-2, \mathbb{Q})$ are in correspondence to the subgroups of $Aut_{\mathbb{Q}}L$, according to the Fundamental Theorem of Galois. Now,

$$S_3 = \{Id, \sigma, \sigma^2, \tau, \sigma\tau, \sigma^2\tau\}$$

Notice that there is a element $\sigma$ of order $3$ generating a cyclic subgroup of order $3$, i.e., $\langle\sigma\rangle$ , and 3 elements of order $2$. What is missing is to identify such elements $\sigma$ and $\tau$ among your automorphisms $\sigma_i$ in order to find exactly the intermediate fields of $L = Gal (X^3-2,\mathbb{Q})$ through Galois correspondence.

Hint: $\sigma = \sigma_2$ (need to check)

Comment: what do you mean by $\sigma =\sigma _2$ need to check ?

Comment: Because it's just a guess, you need to check if it's order $3$. It's better when you build a table of automorphism, easier to identify.

Comment: but $\sigma _2$ has the order 3 no ?

Comment: Yes, that's why my guess. Now find $\tau$. And you may build the intermediate fields.

Comment: therefore $\tau=\sigma _4$ ? But the thing I don't understand is I should have 3 field of degree 3, 1 field of degree 2, 1 field of degree 1 and a last one of degree 6. The field of degree 6 is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2, e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}})$ (assiciated to $\sigma _1$, the field of degree 2 is $\Q(e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}})$ (associated to $\sigma _2$), the three field of degree 3 are $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2),\mathbb Q(e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}\sqrt[3]2),\mathbb Q(e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}}\sqrt[3]2)$ associated to $\sigma _{3,6,5}$, but how can I find the field $\mathbb Q$ ? Because it's not associated by $\sigma _3$.

Comment: If you build a diagram helps a lot, you'll see that if $\theta$ is the function that associates subgroups of $Aut_{\mathbb{Q}}L$ to intermediate fields then $\mathbb{Q} = \theta (Aut_{\mathbb{Q}}L)$.

Comment: I did it, therefore, I remark that $\sigma _3=\sigma _2^2$ and so, the subgroup are $\left<\sigma _1\right>,\left<\sigma _2\right>,\left<\sigma _4\right>,\left<\sigma _5\right>,\left<\sigma _6\right>$ and $\mathfrak S_3$. I'm right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19745/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-idm).

Comment: Enter the chat.